# What kind of beetle is this (2cm long, brown, "V-shaped" body)?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I've seen this brown beetle, which was about 2cm-3cm long (I guess) near Loch Lomond (Scottland) a few days ago.

[image]

What kind of beetle is it?

Comment: Now it's free to use: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stink-bug.jpg

Comment: I agree, it is a forest bug. But be careful, when someone kills it, it produces a extremelly bad smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, that looks like a stink bug, family [Pentatomidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae).

You can see some slightly different coloured ones here on [Insects of Scotland](http://www.insectsofscotland.com/p/true-bugs.html)

Here is a photo of the one that I used to see in the States (From [Master Gardening](http://blog.mastergardening.com/2011/07/a-stink-bug-solution-has-arrived/)):
[image: Stink bug]

Comment: More commonly referred to as **shield bugs** in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a beetle but a shield bug, probably a **forest bug (*Pentatoma rufipes*)**: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_bug). The *Collins Complete Guide to British Wildlife* describes these as widespread in the UK, with adults seen from August to October.

Beetles are from the order [Coleoptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle), bugs ("true bugs", rather than the informal use of the term to mean, basically, any creepy-crawly) are [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera). Beetles have two pairs of wings, but the front pair is hardened and acts like a shell and only the rear pair is used for flying. Bugs have either one or two pairs of wings. The front half of the forewings is usually hardened for protection, but the rear half is unhardened; if there's a second pair of wings, they're usually unhardened and all wings are used for flying.

Comment: In some insects one of the pairs of wings is modified into [halteres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halteres).

Comment: *Pentatoma rufipes* would be my suggestion as well, without knowing the Pentatomidae fauna of the british islands in particular.

Comment: @fileunderwater Good point. I added a reference attesting to them being common in the UK.